# Get MIPS Assembler on QEMU MIPS 32 Instance

Tags: assembly, debian, qemu, mips32

I have successfully booted a QEMU Debian MIPS 32 machine as following the directions here:

https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/mips/

I am struggling to find a way to get a MIPS 32 assembler into that instance. I know about xSPIM, but I would like to try to assemble on QEMU. Does anyone know where I could find a MIPS 32 assembler and pull it from the QEMU instance launched following the aforementioned directions?

Comment: Don't you have the `as` and `ld` commands installed? If no, you'll need the binutils package.

Comment: Please also mention that the system call numbers under Linux and under emulators are different!